# How do one find the index number of 1st quartile, median and 2nd quartile?

Tags: r, statistics

How do I find the index number of the 1st quartile, median and 2nd quartile? I have a data set containing 1006 observations. I could easily find the position of the minimum and maximum value by using

```
match(min(sp500_logreturns), as.numeric(sp500_logreturns))
```

But it just spits out NA if i use `quantile(sp500_logreturns, 0.25)` and `0.5` and `0.75` instead of `min(sp500_logreturns)` in the `match`-function... How could I else find the index number?

Comment: By default, `quantile()` uses `type=7` which does averaging between points. Add the argument `type=1` to `quantile()` to get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. But why is this neccesary if I may ask?

Comment: It comes down to what is meant by the term "quantile".  Suppose you only had 2 values.  What is the 0.7 quantile for that vector of two values?  Or more simply, what is the median for those two values?  One definition is to average the surrounding values, but then (as you discovered) that averaged value may not be in the original vector of values. The same logic holds for much larger vector of values where a quantile does not fall "cleanly" on one value.

Comment: Alright, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly even simpler than using `match` together with a calculation of `quantile` is to simply select the element at the (fractional) position you want after ordering:

Test data:

```
sp500_logreturns=sample(1:100,size=10006,replace=T)
```

For first quartile (0.25):

```
firstq_index=order(sp500_logreturns)[length(sp500_logreturns)*0.25]
# check:
mean(sp500_logreturns<sp500_logreturns[firstq_index])
# [1] 0.2467519
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The first comment did the trick, but I might try your solution aswell. Have a nice day!